# Store App: Sqlite & Bing.Maps SDK fail WACK validation

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

After installing the latest version of Bing.Maps and subsequent try to create store app package ( Release x86 ) the WACK fails with following error message:

Bing.Maps

```
API ??0COMException@Platform@@Q$AAA@H@Z in vccorlib110.dll is not supported for this application type. Bing.Maps.dll calls this API.
API ??0ChangedStateException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110.dll is not supported for this application type. Bing.Maps.dll calls this API.
API ??0Delegate@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110.dll is not supported for this application type. Bing.Maps.dll calls this API.
```

and Sqlite

```
API __CppXcptFilter in msvcr110.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API __clean_type_info_names_internal in msvcr110.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API __crtTerminateProcess in msvcr110.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API __crtUnhandledException in msvcr110.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API __dllonexit in msvcr110.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
```

The VC++ reference is added.

[image: References]

The application runs in debug mode, release mode and on a real win 8 device installed with power-shell script.

Any suggestions are welcome :)

s.

Answer (score 0):

I have a store app that use bing maps sdk v1.313.825.0.
It failed WACK with same errors. But, It could passed the Store's certification.
Have you tried submission?

Comment: fortunately I have another PC, very same configuration, on which the WACK brings no errors but it's still interesting to find out why it fails on my computer :)